# App request/Invite through Facebook API using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building an app and the client wants the following logic:

1. User logs in to the app.
2. User selects a Friend.
3. User selects a gift that the User will send to his Friend.
4. User writes a message to his Friend.
5. Friend receives a SECRET notification about the gift.

With "SECRET" I mean that Friend will not be able to see WHO is the User that sent the gift.

So the concrete question is how to send a notification to the FRIEND without a clue about the USER that sent it? I think is not possible but I want to be sure and check with the experts.

And if it's not possible, what do you recommend to accomplish something like this? Should I use the app request dialog and hope that the Friend will see it? Is there any other FB API tool I can use?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Canvas app or website integrated?

Comment: Even with the request dialog the user will see who send the request. You could only send a notification or app request if the receiving user was a user of your app already. Otherwise, it’s not possible to do what your client wants “anonymously”.

Comment: @SahilMittal It's a canvas app.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah thanks for your opinion I think it is not possible too but I wanted to be sure before making a move. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with FB's API. As explained already by @CBroe.
You can send a request notification if the user uses your app. However, You can do one thing but that won't be completely `anonymous`.

You can send the friend a notification from the user and make it just an invite to try the application and after the friend uses your app (authenticates), your app can then send a notification and say someone left a `SECRET` message for them. This could be after few hours or instant, Whatever you/your client prefers. However as i said, this won't be completely anonymous nor it's hard to guess who left the message unless the friend isn't smart enough to know who that could be.

Answer (score 0):

With the beta Notification API something similar would be possible, but only if the receiver has authenticated your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/#impl